# A more concise way than mine to find widgets and their layout locations by name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pytest, pyqt5

I am writing functional tests for a PyQt5 MainWindow GUI. Currently I am checking for whether the correct widget is in the correct coordinate of a grid layout. I have determined how to find a widget by its objectName, and figured out the hierarchy of modules needed to "dig down" to a widget in the GUI's (grid) layout, but I feel that I must be doing this the hard way. I have been reading through the PyQt4/5 documentation and searching for similar questions on SO but haven't uncovered tools that would simplify my task.

Ideally, I would like commands similar to those in the following pseudocode:

```
Bob_widget = widget['Bob']  # lookup widget by objectName
assert Bob_widget.layout.coordinates == (0, 0)
```

The functionality of the first line of the pseudocode could be done by passing each widget name and type into a findChild method and then making a dictionary, but I wonder if there's a built-in equivalent.

The second line of pseudocode is more of a pain. How to tunnel down through the GUI to find the widgets took some research. For my GUI code below:

```
import sys
from collections import namedtuple

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout,
                             QLabel, QDoubleSpinBox)

gui_userinput = namedtuple('gui_userinput', ['key', 'string', 'value', 'range'])

variable_a = gui_userinput(key='variable_a', string='Variable A', value=165.00,
                           range=(0.00, 10000.00))
variable_b = gui_userinput(key='variable_b', string='Variable B', value=135.00,
                           range=(0.00, 10000.00))

gui_userinput_order = (variable_a, variable_b)


class Gui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(Gui, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setObjectName('toplevel')
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        centralWidget.setObjectName('centralwidget')
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        centralLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.setObjectName('centrallayout')

        for i, widget in enumerate(gui_userinput_order):

            wlabel = QLabel(widget.string)
            wlabel.setObjectName(widget.key + '_label')

            wbox = QDoubleSpinBox()
            wbox.setObjectName(widget.key)
            wbox.setRange(*widget.range)
            wbox.setValue(widget.value)

            centralLayout.addWidget(wlabel, 0, i)
            centralLayout.addWidget(wbox, 1, i)

        centralWidget.setLayout(centralLayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Gui()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

fetching a widget from the MainWindow requires a statement like:

```
widget_0_0 = self.ui.centralWidget().layout()\
            .itemAtPosition(0, 0).widget()
```

"The GUI has a central widget that has a (grid) layout that has a widget container at grid coordinate (0, 0) that holds the widget I want."

So I can code tests riffing off of the minimal example below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDoubleSpinBox, QLabel

import mini_ui

app = QApplication(sys.argv)


class TestMainGUi:

    def setup(self):
        self.ui = mini_ui.Gui()

    def test_all_widgets_exist(self):
        """The user finds the expected labels and doublespinboxes."""
        for widget in mini_ui.gui_userinput_order:
            found_box = self.ui.findChild(QDoubleSpinBox, widget.key)
            assert found_box.value() == widget.value
            found_label = self.ui.findChild(QLabel, widget.key + '_label')
            assert found_label.text() == widget.string

    def test_label_0_0(self):
        """The user sees a label for 'Variable A' in the top left corner."""
        label_a = self.ui.findChild(QLabel, 'variable_a_label')
        print('Found', label_a, 'named', label_a.objectName(), 'in GUI.')
        widget_0_0 = self.ui.centralWidget().layout()\
            .itemAtPosition(0, 0).widget()
        print('Found widget type', type(widget_0_0), 'at grid 0, 0')
        print('It is named: ', widget_0_0.objectName())

        assert widget_0_0.text() == 'Variable A'
        assert widget_0_0 is label_a

    def test_alternate_widget_acces(self):
        """Just hacking away trying to find a more terse widget reference"""
        label_a = self.ui.findChild(QLabel, 'variable_a_label')

        assert 1 == 1

    def teardown(self):
        pass
```

and change the second test to iteratively match component widgets to grid coordinate widgets, but that feels wrong. Besides being convoluted, if anything about the GUI changes to alter the hierarchy, the test won't work--the test code must be aware of the GUI's fine structure.

Is there a more concise, more robust way to test a GUI layout's contents? Are there built-in tools that I'm missing?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution for finding the layout by name, which means that the test can now be unaware of the exact GUI structure.

The name of the layout is **lost** if you assign the name to the layout before applying it to the centralWidget with `centralWidget.setLayout()`. If you set the layout of the centralWidget, and **then** give a name to `centralWidget.layout()`, the layout can be found by name.

So, amend mini_ui as:

```
centralWidget.setLayout(centralLayout)
centralWidget.layout().setObjectName('centrallayout')
```

and then the functional test can find the layout and assign it to a variable:

```
def test_alternate_widget_access(self):
    """Just hacking away trying to find a more terse widget reference"""
    main_layout = self.ui.findChild(QGridLayout, 'centrallayout')
    found_widget = main_layout.itemAtPosition(0, 0).widget()
```